# Using Windows Firewall programmatically

Tags: c++, firewall, windows-firewall-api

I have difficulties to find anything related to Windows firewall (about how to add aplications to except list, close ports or disable internet access to some applications) in C++. I found even MS site shows examples in Visual Basic.

Where I can find examples in C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Check the article [Exercising the Firewall using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726(v=VS.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Kirill, can u paste other links?

Comment: @returner, check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/WinXPSP2Firewall.aspx) sample from codeproject.com

Answer (score 0):

When working with Windows Vista and later, the [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124(v=vs.85).aspx) API is also available.